# how to define predefined pch values and new pch shape in same R code

Tags: r, plot, pch

I am trying to put different shape using pch. but it's not giving expected output.

```
legend("topleft",
             legend = c("Upper limit ","Estimated","Lower limit"), 
             col = c("black","black","black"), 
             pch = c('-','19','-'), 
             #bty="n",
             cex=1.2,
             text.col="black",
             horiz=F,
             inset=c(0.1,0.1)
             )
```

Expected output should be :
- Upper limit,
0(pch=19) Estimated,
- Lower limit
but the actual output is:
-Upper limit,
1 estimated,
- Lower Limit.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for `lty`.

```
plot(1:10, type="n")
legend("topleft", legend=c("Upper limit ", "Estimated", "Lower limit"), 
       pch=c(NA, 19, NA), lty=c(1, NA, 1), cex=1.2, inset=c(0.1, 0.1))
```

[image]